# How can I prevent Delay in loading a path from the Routes array in angular

Tags: angular7, angular7-router

I have lazy loading implemented. Divided into modules. And set up the routes. Everything is working.

I have doubt regarding the order of module loading. I noticed that, if I try to load any module down in the list of routes, it loads all modules above it first.

for eg:  if I try to load ActionModule, then it loads all modules above it (or goes through all the routes above it), before coming to action, and this causes delay.

Can I change the routes in some way, that it loads only the required module?

Here's my
[routing.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND1WD.png)

and
[browser network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHJZv.png) which shows my problem.

```
//routing.ts(in text format)
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
    {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent, children: [
 
        { path: 'blank', component: BlankComponent, data: { breadcrumb: '' }, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoardComponent, data: { breadcrumb: '' }, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'iframedashboard', component: iframeDashBoardComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Iframe Dashboard' }, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
         
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/operations2/order-maintenance/order.module#OrderModule'},
 
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/administration/administration.module#AdministrationModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/base/base.module#BaseModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/cms/cms.module#CMSModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/operations/operation.module#OperationModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup/system-setup.module#SystemSetupModule'},

        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/operations2/ordertemplate/order-template.module#OrderTemplateModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/operations2/upload-file/upload-file.module#UploadFileModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/operations2/order-trace/order-trace.module#OrderTraceModule'},

        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup2/action/action.module#ActionModule'},// 
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup2/rule-groups-maintenances/rule-group.module#RuleGroupModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup2/rule/rule.module#RuleModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup2/workcellType/work-cell-type.module#WorkCellTypeModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup2/channel-maintenance/channel-maintenance.module#ChannelMaintenanceModule'},
        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup2/shift-calendar/shift-calendar.module#ShiftCalendarModule'},

        { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/system-setup3/system-setup3.module#SystemSetup3Module'}

    ]
},
{ path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Error' } },
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    // preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,  // <- comment this line for activate lazy load
    // useHash: true
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, while I'm not sure what the browser network tab means:

Is it loading all the modules prior to the correct module

OR

<s>Is it just searching through all prior modules, to get to the correct module</s> (Edited for grammer)
Is it just searching through all prior routes, to get to the correct module route

We'll never know:
Anyways I solved this problem by adding a loading spinner/indicator :)